# How do I create an ad hoc network in Windows 8?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8-preview, ad-hoc-network

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to create an ad hoc wireless network in Windows 8. Here is what happens if I follow the steps from Windows 7:

1. Right click the network icon and click "Network and Sharing Center":

   [image]
2. Click "Set up a new connection or network":

   [image]
3. Where is the option to create an ad hoc network?

   [image]

Therefore I have two related questions:

- Did I miss something? Is it in there somewhere and I just haven't found it yet?
- If this feature is not available, is there a tool somewhere I can use that provides this capability?

Further information:

- I have an Intel Wireless WiFi 4965 AGN adapter.
- I tried the Intel PRO wireless tool and it didn't offer an ad hoc option.

Comment: I'm not sure if this means anything but: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/ad-hoc-wifi-windows-8-cp/984258e8-851b-459b-9f6a-7f8bdf46ac54?tm=1331571370415

Comment: This is what you're looking for http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-create-wireless-ad-hoc-internet-connection-in-windows-8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [**Connectify**](http://www.connectify.me/) which is a third-party solution, you should be able to come around with the Lite features.

> Transform your Windows laptop into a Wi-Fi hotspot at the click of a button so you can share a single Internet connection with your friends, co-workers, and mobile devices.
>
> [image]

Otherwise, try to see if you can use `netsh` to [set up an ad-hoc network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277137/create-ad-hoc-wireless-from-command-prompt-or-batch/4625774#4625774).

> To start simply use this commands
>
> ```
> netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=LocalAdHoc key=password
> netsh wlan start hostednetwork
> ```
>
> And to stop it
>
> ```
> netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
> ```

Comment: When I run the commands, I get "The hosted network couldn't be started. The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation." However, Connectify works *awesome*, **thank you!**

Comment: good solution, but that command assigns a dynamic ip address every time windows restart, do you know how to assign an ip address manually?

Comment: After some further research, I think the commands you've provided create a full-blown access point and not an ad-hoc network. And because a lot of wireless cards do not support AP mode (mine included), the error from my comment above will be displayed.

Comment: @TomWijsman : and do I do if [I have devices](http://superuser.com/q/944015/282033) which don’t support wpa2 psk ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I can confirm that there are only two setting in MY Windows 8 Network and Sharing Center

- Setup a network connection
- Troubleshooting.

However, if your mission is to connect to a wireless network then I can help.

Click 'Change Adapter Settings'
Right click your Wireless Adapter
Click 'Connect / Disconnect'

Now I get a 'Networks' settings list which displays all the nearby wireless connections.